# Best way to find the coordinates between two points?

Tags: coordinates

So I'm trying to find the location between point A & B. Point A will be my phone  and point be will be a dot on a small object. Point A is a point in the middle of my phone with an X/Y axis. Using the front facing camera on an iPhone, point B attached to the small object, moves into the cameras view. Point B will never be more than a foot away from point A at any time.

Is it possible to determine the exact coordinates of point B in relation to point A's X/Y axis (Within a millimeter or so)? Would a signal need to be sent between the two points, or would the camera be able to pick up point B and determine its coordinates on point A's X/Y axis?

I've attached an image below to hopefully explain what I am trying to describe a little better.

[image: example]

Comment: You are able to determine the `dx,dy` in pixels. But since you don't have the depth information of the scene and you're using an uncalibrated camera, you cannot determine their distance in world space.

Comment: Is it possible to determine the depth as well as calibrate the camera?

Comment: Is this the rabbit hole you choose? Look up *structure from motion* and follow the references to get an idea of what you're asking for. And look up camera calibration while you're at it. This is probably not what you want to do, but you didn't specify what you're trying to do this for.

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates of two points are A(-6, 0) and B(10, 4). Find the coordinates of the point C on the y-axis such that AC=BC.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).